# Wired network connection drops every 3 minutes

Tags: networking, internet

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10, with Gnome. It is connected to the internet by LAN cable to a router that in turn connects to an optical fibre modem.

Every three minutes or so, my wired connection simply cuts off. It comes on again after about a minute.

[image: Dropped connected]

This only happens on one computer out of three on my LAN, so I know it is not a network problem. It happens when I am running any application, browser or music streaming, or anything, so I know it is not application specific.

This only started happening within the last few days. Something might have automatically updated, but I have made no settings changes or configurations of my own at all recently, so this is not a result of anything done manually.

I have tried rebooting, restarting the network manager, rebooting the router, and turning off any firewalls. So far, nothing has helped.

Why does my network keep dropping on this computer, and how do I get it to be stable again?

Comment: hard to know, my only suggestion is to disable ipv6

Comment: Have you tried to replace the plug of your ethernet cable?

Comment: Try `dmesg | grep -e eth -ie dhcp` to see if the kernel logged anything when it happens. Also check if the blinking lights in your Ethernet port go dark when it happens again.